# What is the difference between logical statements and statement variables?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

For the following two question

Let P, Q, and R be logical statements. Use a truth table to prove that_______.

Let P, Q, and R be statement variables, and suppose that the logical expression_______ is false.

The blank is two expressions which I don't know how to type those symbols, hope it doesn't matter.

Comment: This question cannot really be answered without context. (On the one hand, Natalie's answer is more plausible regarding the author's intended meaning. On the other hand, Bram does have a point that statement variables need not be atomic. And the blanked-out examples aren't helping.)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Statement variables are atomic statements, i.e. statements with no connectives in them. Statement variables are usually written as letters $p, q, r, \ldots$.

Logical statements are any statements composed of statement variables and, possibly, connectives. For example: $p$, $\neg p$, $p \land q$, $(q \lor p) \to (r \lor q)$, $\ldots$.

Every statement variable makes for a logical statement, but not every logical statement is a single statement variable.

Answer (score 1):

A logical statement like $P$ is meant to be a specific statement. For example, $P$ could mean 'It is raining'.

A statement variable is something we use to indicate that we are dealing with *some* statement ... but we don't know what it is.

It is like the difference between $2$ and $x$ when doing algebra. The $2$ is a specific number, but the $x$ is some unknown number.